# AWS - Give readonly permissions for all services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies

Is there a way in AWS to give readonly permissions to *all* services via a central policy? Currently, am forced to do this per service, like for IAM below -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:Get*",
            "iam:List*",
            "iam:Generate*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
}
```

Having to do this for each and every resource is error prone and tedious. How can we define a policy to give read-only for all services.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [AWS managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/security-iam-awsmanpol.html) named [ReadOnlyAccess](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess):

> the ReadOnlyAccess AWS managed policy provides read-only access to all AWS services and resources. When a service launches a new feature, AWS adds read-only permissions for new operations and resources.